# Moving a 3D object on the other Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have two 3D objects, a sphere and a car.
I would like to move the car on the sphere. But I can not put the car on the sphere, as if the sphere was ground!
http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/6559/gv2h.jpg

Comment: I found this example http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html.

But you could tell me how to put an object on the other.

As one of the objects was the floor, and other objects that move on the ground.
Because I just thought about collision between objects and in fact I would like to put one over the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try Physijs, which provides good features on collision detection etc. Check it's examples.